# Newform.aspx in a dialog box

Tags: 2010

I have a button which redirect to newform.aspx .
I want the newform.aspx to be opened in a dialog box .
currently i cannot see this thing opening in a popup , hw to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution ,

## Visual Wp :

Add below javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function AddWebParts(addedwebparts) {

          var varUrl = "<%=varPageUrl%>";
          var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
          options.url = varUrl + addedwebparts;
          options.allowMaximize = true;
          options.showClose = true;
          options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
          SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

          function CloseCallback(dialogResult) {
              if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {

                 __doPostBack('AddWebpartsToPage'); // this will post back the page with the argument specified
              }
          }
      }
</script>
```

## Page  load :

```
varPageUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url.ToString();
appendurl = "/Lists/QuickLinks/NewForm.aspx" + "?Source=" + Page.Request.Url.ToString();
btnQuickLinks.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:AddWebParts('" + appendurl + "');return false;");
```

## after button click your changes should be updated so write below code in page load

```
string eventArgument = this.Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
if (eventArgument != null)
{
    if (eventArgument.Contains("AddWebpartsToPage"))
    {
        //BindGridDATA();
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple example:

```
<a title="aTitle" onmouseover="javascript:this.style.cursor='hand'; 
    onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('http://path/to/NewForm.aspx';);
    return false;">
    link Text
</a>
```

You can read more about SP.UI.ModalDialog at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408909.aspx

Comment: Can i add Source ID to the url and send ? like onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('http://path/to/NewForm.aspx ?sourceid+"string"=';);

Comment: You're just passing a URL to the ShowPopupDialog function, so you can add any values to it that you want to.

Comment: wehn i click button on newform.aspx , i need it to come back to my home page

Comment: By "come back to my home page" do you mean closing the modal window, or physically redirecting the parent window? You'd probably need to do a little more work on the JavaScript to accomplish that. Passing "?source=/path/to/page.aspx" will most likely redirect to the page within the modal window.

Comment: Also, I just noticed in your comment that you're using ?sourceid... it needs to be "source", so the example would be: "path/to/NewForm.aspx?source="+string

Answer (score 0):

Just go to list settings then go to advance settings, under general settings click on advance settings, and then at the bottom of the page click yes for "Launch forms in a dialog?". All your forms will get open in a modal dialog.