# how to open hyperlink list item in modal dialog box

Tags: list, modal-dialog, hyperlink

I have created a datagrid using javascript. In that I am displaying top 4 items of my sharepoint list. Now I want to open hyperlink list item in modal dialog box on the click of that hyperlink. Please suggest javascript or jquery approach.

Comment: Do you want to open view item form  or edit item form?

Comment: I want to open view item form

Comment: Your question is described [here](https://alinimer.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/open-pages-and-forms-in-modal-dialog-for-sharepoint-2013/), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384513/how-to-open-new-list-item-form-in-modal-dialog-in-a-sharepoint-2010-page-from-di), and in [google](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&newwindow=1&es_sm=122&q=sharepoint%20open%20form%20in%20dialog&oq=sharepoint%20open%20form%20in%20dialog&gs_l=serp.3..0i71l7.0.0.0.443154.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1c..62.serp..0.0.0.hvQ15X04_yE)

Comment: Check this https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/

Answer (score 7):

To open the view item form you need to open `DispForm.aspx` page for the List Item in a Modal Dialog. The URL for the list item will be something like `http://server/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=1` where ID is the list item ID. To open it in a modal dialog use the following code snippet.

```
function openDialog(pageUrl) {  
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(   
     {  
       url: pageUrl,
       width: 500,  
       height: 500,  
       title: "Title of the Dialog"  
     }  
  );  
}
```

The above snippet has been taken from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/95576/20540).

You can also look at these:

- [Newform.aspx in a dialog box](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/20473/20540)
- [Create a link to display, edit and create new items from a dialog (layover) in SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2014/09/23/create-a-link-to-display-edit-and-create-new-items-from-a-dialog-layover-in-sharepoint.aspx) (Based on SP 2013 but code should work for SP 2010 also)

Comment: Thnks Naveen. But I want to open modal dialog on the click of the list item hyperlink which is already getting displayed on page load. When and how should I called this function that u have written ?

Comment: @Ruchi: You would be requried to call the `openDialog` from `<a>` tag. You can do this via `href="javascript:openDialog()"` or `onclick="openDialog()"`. You will have to contruct the URL based by supplying server name, list name and ID of the list item.

Comment: Naveen here is my code that adds list items on the datagrid 
function AddRowToTable1(name, modified, ID) {

            var url = "http://synpunspd0177:23598/Lists/Broadcasts/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + ID;

            $("#BroadcastsdataTable").append('<tr>' +
                                                    '<td class="tablenews"> <a href= ' + url + '>' + name + '</a>  ' + modified + ' </td>' +
                                                    '</tr>');


How to open list items that are displaying in datagrid as modal popup when clicked

Comment: @Ruchi: You will have to write something like `"<a href=\"javascript:openDialog('" + url + "')\>"`.

Comment: it is not working. Please suggest any other way..

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the relevant file (`SP.UI.Dialog.js`) has been loaded first.

```
function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
var options = {
    url: pageUrl,
    title: 'Title of the Dialog',
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
}
```

Here is a posting with some additional useful details:  [Tips & Tricks: SharePoint 2013 Modal Dialogs](http://blog.collabware.com/2013/03/22/tips-tricks-sharepoint-2013-modal-dialogs/)

Answer (score 1):

This JavaScript should inject the PopUp code in your page, affecting all link tags:

```
var links=getElementByTitle("a","linkTitle");
var origin=links;
var temp="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('" + origin + "', null, 640, 480)";
links.href=temp;

function getElementByTitle(tagName,elementTitle){
    var elementTag;
    var els=document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var elsLen=els.length;
    var pattern=new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + elementTitle + "(\\s|$)");
    for (var i=j=0; i < els.length; i++){
        if (elementTitle.toUpperCase()==els[i].title.toUpperCase()){
        elementTag=els[i];
        j++;
    }}
 return elementTag;
}
```

Comment: helped! thanks I just changed els[i].title.toUpperCase() to els[i].text.toUpperCase()